# Add a linked list to another linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to add a linkedlist to another linkedlist using a method called addList in the MyLinkedList class. What I'm stuck on is how to implement the method so that I can add a linkedlist to another linkedlist of index location of my choosing.

Here's what I have in MyLinkedList:

```
public void addList(int index, E e){
    if(index == 0){
        addFirst(e);
    } else if (index >= size){
        addLast(e);
    }
    else{
        Node<E> current = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++){
            current = current.next;
        }
        Node<E> temp = current.next;
        current.next = new Node<E>(e);
        (current.next).next = temp;
        size++;
    }
}
```

I know this method won't work, I've tried it.
In my program itself, I have these:

```
public class linkedlistwork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLinkedList<String> alpha = new MyLinkedList<String>();
        alpha.add("hello");
        alpha.add("world");
        alpha.add("this");

        System.out.println(alpha);

        MyLinkedList<String> beta = new MyLinkedList<String>();
        beta.add("is");
        beta.add("java");
        beta.add("rocks");

        System.out.println(beta);

        alpha.addList(1, beta);
        System.out.println(alpha);
    }
}
```

The correct output would be something like:

```
OUTPUT:
[hello, is, java, rocks, world, this]
```

My program would not run, an error occurred in this line

```
alpha.addList(1, beta);
```

on the "beta" part, it says:

method addList in class MyLinkedList cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,String
  found: int,MyLinkedList
  reason: actual argument MyLinkedList cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class MyLinkedList

How would I fix my method so that I can use it correctly?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please add in vector definitions?

Comment: I think you'll need your addList method to have the generic in there:

`public void <E> addList(int index, E e) {`

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that your addList method signature is the problem.
It should look like:

```
public void addList(int index, List<E> list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a method for adding `MyLinkedList<String>`. Something like this would do

```
public void addList(int index, MyLinkedList<E> beta){
//Somehow loop through the MyLinkedList, and do this.
   add(index+i,beta(i));
}
```